# SplitView.PaneClosed event is available but not for PaneOpened

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10, uwp-xaml

According to the https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.splitview.paneclosed.aspx there is no PaneOpened event for the SplitView control, only PaneClosed event for the SplitView control that exists.

I have a Button control inside a SplitView pane that needs to change in size according whether the pane is opened or closed. So my plan is I will place a piece of code that will change the button size wider in the PaneOpened event, and restore it back to the small size in PaneClosed event. But it seems there is no PaneOpened event.

Any other way that I can achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks to the new [RegisterPropertyChangedCallback](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.dependencyobject.registerpropertychangedcallback.aspx) in UWP, you can now monitor property change events of any `DependencyProperty`, including native ones.

```
public SplitViewPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    this.splitView.RegisterPropertyChangedCallback(SplitView.IsPaneOpenProperty, IsPaneOpenPropertyChanged);
}

private void IsPaneOpenPropertyChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyProperty dp)
{
    // put your logic here
}
```