# How to customize splitview in Windows 10?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I am currently working on a Splitview Control which contains some menu options in SplitView Pane and a Grid in SplitView Content section. When the split view pane is opened its content gets hidden. Is it possible to move that slightly left like the following screenshot?

[image]

My basic split view implementation is

```
 <SplitView x:Name="OptionsSplitView" OpenPaneLength="200" PanePlacement="Right"
           DisplayMode="Overlay">

        <SplitView.Pane>
            <ListView x:Name="OptionsList"
                      Margin="10,10,0,0"
                      Grid.Row="1"
                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                      ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource GenericListViewContainerStyle}"
                      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource OptionsListItemTemplate}"
                      SelectionChanged="OptionsList_SelectionChanged">
            </ListView>

        </SplitView.Pane>
        <SplitView.Content>
           <Grid/>
        </SplitView.Content>
       </SplitView>
```

Please suggest is it possible to customize split view as per screenshot?

Comment: Does your splitview covers the all content area?

Comment: No only some part of it. I want to move content left side when split view opens. I tried using DisplayMode as Inline but it shrinks my split view content.

Comment: Set right Margin When pane is opened and set it back to original when pane is closed. To get event when Pane open and close do check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31636440/windows-10-uwp-splitview-paneclosed-event-is-available-but-not-for-paneopened

Comment: Let me know if it works for you ,i will be post as answer so that other also can refer it.

Comment: Yes it worked you can post an answer. I will accept that answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bingo,

You can achieve it by just setting Right Margin of content whenever Pane Open or close.

Do refer Below link to get pane open & close event.

[(Windows 10 UWP) SplitView.PaneClosed event is available but not for PaneOpened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31636440/windows-10-uwp-splitview-paneclosed-event-is-available-but-not-for-paneopened)

Comment: Please give my question also upvote if you found it useful.:-)

Answer (score 0):

Change your Splitview `DisplayMode` option to `CompactInline` or `CompactOverlay` as per your requirement

Comment: This doesn't work. I want to achieve this when user clicks on Menu icon.

Comment: Which screen you want to shift. Options one is the one that's supposed to overlay over your below content right

Comment: Yes, I want to shift the left side content when Hamburger menu is clicked. I can't use CompactInline and CompactOverlay because it displayed when the page is displayed.

Comment: Then how about `Inline` because thats how the content would be moved and also you wont see it displayed.

Comment: it gives the same effect but left side content is shrink and doesn't look good and also, I want to close the menu when a user clicks on content. You can also check Reside Menu in Android and iOS.I want to achieve same.

Comment: The left side menu shrinks because you are using Inline-The Pane and the content area share the user space side by side and this remains in the screen always even when the user clicks anywhere in the  content area. For closing the menu inside your Listview clicked item you can always call `OptionsSplitView.IsPaneOpen` back to False

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108370/discussion-between-jerin-and-kinjan-bhavsar).